# @import 'bootstrap' raise an Action Controller:Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bootstrap-sass

I'm developping a Rails app on windows 8 (Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3p125) with a partitioned disk .

My Rails install is on drive "S", my app is on drive "J".

In my gem file I have "gem 'bootstrap-sass' ". As recommended I use "@import 'bootstrap' in my bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss file.

This raise an error :

```
Showing J:/Users/Anne-Sophie/Documents/2.web/novaxones/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

different prefix: "S:/" and "J:/Users/Anne-Sophie/Documents/2.web/novaxones/app/assets/stylesheets"
  (in J:/Users/Anne-Sophie/Documents/2.web/novaxones/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-and-overrides.css.scss)
```

If I remove "@import 'bootstrap'" from my css.scss file the error disappears... How can I fix that to be able to use bootstrap ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around on github (https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/96).

Not ideal but it works !